# When I get filter then data is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Normally data fetch is good but when category data find and so filter method then get data is undefined. I think my data fetch is not right!

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const PostDataLoad = () => {
    const [postData, setPostdata]=useState([])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/public/PostDatas.json')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            setPostdata(data)
        })
    },[])
    const Category1 = postData.filter(findCategory=> findCategory.category === 'Technology')
    
    return [postData,Category1]
};

export default PostDataLoad;
```

I want to get data load in filter method.

Comment: `PostDataLoad ` is incorrectly named, it should be `usePostDataLoad` if it is a React hook. `Array.prototype.find` returns undefined if no element is found that passes filtering condition. Are you sure you have the correct `category` property value? What is the logged output of `data`? Can you [edit] to clarify what exactly the issue/problem is, what debugging steps you have taken are, a more complete [mcve] that includes example `postData` value that is fetched?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the exported `PostDataLoad` function is a hook, there are a few things that you need to fix:

1. By convention, [the function name of a hook should start with `use`](https://react.dev/learn/reusing-logic-with-custom-hooks#hook-names-always-start-with-use)
2. The variable `Category1` will only be computed once (the initial call) and will not be recomputed. Move the logic of calculating the return value inside the `useEffect()`'s fetch call:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const usePostDataLoad = () => {
    const [returnValue, setReturnValue]=useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch('/public/PostDatas.json')
        .then(res=> res.json())
        .then(data=>{
            console.log(data);
            setReturnValue([
                data,
                data.filter(findCategory=> findCategory.category === 'Technology')
            ]);
        })
    },[])
    
    return returnValue;
};

export default usePostDataLoad;
```

Comment: Point 2 is incorrect. `Category1` is computed any time `PostDataLoad` is called. OP is returning the current `postData` state ***and*** this computed `Category1` value.